# Is there a name for this Americano/Long Black Variation?

Tags: espresso

I am quite sensitive to caffeine so when brewing espresso I want to extend the enjoyment of my drink. An americano to me is way too much water and I lose a lot of what I think makes an espresso amazing. No water added and I drink the coffee too quickly and find myself wanting another. This is my new recipe: to help extend my drink. I brew a standard double espresso of about 36-40g and add that same weight in water. If I made a 40g espresso I would add 40g more of water. I think of it like a cortado but instead of milk I use water.

I am wondering if this is an actual drink and if it has a name or if it is just some crazy successful experiment I made up.

Answer (score 2):

I mostly drink Americano's  at my favorite coffee roaster, Kaladi Brothers Coffee, ( *barista's take a two week training before they are allowed to pull shots for customers* ) but occasionally i get a Stretched Lungo. ( *French Press Exclusively at home* )

[Lungo](https://www.coffeefeature.com/what-is-lungo-coffee/)

The link will educate you as to the particulars of the Lungo.

> Both lungos and Americanos are made using an espresso machine and
>   water. Which makes you ask ‘Is a lungo an Americano?’. The method of
>   making both these coffees sounds the same, but there is a big
>   difference. When you make a lungo, all of the water is brewed and it
>   generally comes out shorter than an Americano.
>
> When you make an Americano you add the water after the espresso has
>   been pulled from the espresso machine. Americanos also usually come in
>   larger cups so you can add as much water as you like to the coffee.
>
> Lungos should be served in a slightly smaller cup because you don’t
>   need to add any water after making it. But if you really like, no one
>   will probably judge you if you do!
>
> Both coffees are made with ground coffee and roughly the same amount
>   of water. So you’d expect them to taste the same right? Wrong. Adding
>   the water after the espresso has been pulled gives you a weaker
>   flavored coffee. Having the water pass through the ground coffee
>   granules, as they do in a Lungo, gives you a much stronger flavored
>   coffee. Great for those of you who like a strong dark coffee to kick
>   start your day!

Comment: Based on that article it would just be an americano then. Just a really short americano. My process is brewing the espresso first then adding water to the shot not brewing all the water through the shot. Every americano I have had has been 6-12oz where mine comes usually out to 3-4oz. I think I'll stick with "Short Americano" as its name